# Changing directory in PowerShell to folder name containing Special Chars

Tags: powershell

I am currently at **Users** folder and want to get to **Dockers**  folder.

I am not perform this due to the `\OneDrive - xxxxx, zzz\`

```
cd C:\Users\anmolparida\OneDrive - xxxxx, zzz\Work\Dockers\
```

Error

```
PS C:\Users> cd C:\Users\anmolparida\OneDrive - xxxxx, zzz\Work\Dockers\
Set-Location : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-'.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd C:\Users\anmolparida\OneDrive - xxxxx, zzz\Work\Dockers\
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Comment: You need quotes: `cd "C:\Users\anmolparida\OneDrive - xxxxx, zzz\Work\Dockers\"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cd 'C:\Users\anmolparida\OneDrive - xxxxx, zzz\Work\Dockers\'
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose it with single quotes:

```
cd 'C:\Users\anmolparida\OneDrive - xxxxx, zzz\Work\Dockers\'
```

Double quotes should work, too:

```
cd "C:\Users\anmolparida\OneDrive - xxxxx, zzz\Work\Dockers\"
```

If you don't use double quotes, then powershell takes them as separate arguments, so `Set-Location` fails, but when you quote regarded as value for single argument, `-Path`.

Comment: Consider improving the answer by explaining the _why_ part too. As of now, there's _how_ - using quotes - but no explanation how the answer works and what is the root cause.